# javascript data tables with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, datatables, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate DataTables.js (http://datatables.net) with an app which uses twitter bootstrap library. It seems like DataTable doesn't work well with twitter bootstrap. I'm not sure its the css or js thats conflicting.

How can I integrate DataTables.js with Twitter Bootstrap?  Are there any other data tables libraries that work well with Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: can you show us some code and detail more the "doesn't work well" part?

Answer (score 19):

It is actually quite easy to integrate Bootstrap and DataTables such that your fully featured DataTables will match the same look and feel of the rest of your site.
Here is the link : http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap

**For Bootstrap v2.x.x: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2**

Comment: Or for the just released bootstrap 2.0: http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2

Comment: Oh, but time marches on.  What about version 3 now?

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 3, use this [plugin](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/integration/bootstrap/3).

> **[DataTables Plugins](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins)**
>
> This repository contains a collection of plug-ins
> for the jQuery DataTables table enhancer. These plug-ins are feature
> enhancing for the DataTables library, adding extra options to core
> functionality such as additional sort algorithms, API methods and
> pagination controls. The plug-ins should not be confused with
> DataTables "extras" which are more significant software libraries
> which add additional features to DataTables.

Comment: and [here's the official documentation on how to use those plugin files](http://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

#### SOLUTION

- Use [Download Builder](http://datatables.net/download/index) to generate links to JS/CSS files and include Bootstrap styling and Twitter Bootstrap library (if needed).
- Include generated JS/CSS links into your project.
- Use classes `table table-striped table-bordered` for your `<table>` as shown below:

  ```
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  ```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxk6o3xm/34/) for code and demonstration.